# Oracle connection with port, service name, and database from C# (ORA-12514

Tags: c#, database, oracle, ora-12514

I'm new to Oracle.  Trying to connect C# windows app to an Oracle database but can't seem to establish a proper connection.  Keep getting exception: "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor".  I have to specify the port, service name, and database name in the connection string because the service id has access to multiple databases. I know that the values in the string are valid (valid server, valid serviceid, valid username, password, etc) because I have a third-party tool that is able to connect using the same parameters from a wizard.  I've tried a lot of different ways to format the connection string but I always get the same 12514 error.  In the code example, you'll see three formats (cxn, cxn2, and cxn3), I've tried each of them but get the same error.

```
        string cxn = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyServerName)(PORT=MyPortNumber))" +
            "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyServiceId)));User Id=MyUserName; Password=MyPassword;";

        string cxn2 = "DATA SOURCE=MyServerName:MyPortNumber/MyUserName;" +
            "PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=MyUserName; password=MyPassword; Pooling = False;";

        string cxn3 = "DATA SOURCE=MyServerName:MyPortNumber/MyServiceId;" +
            "PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=MyUserName; password=MyPassword; Pooling = False;";

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cxn3))
        {
            string sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM PERSONS";
            using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sqlSelect, conn))
            {
                var table = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(table);

                if (table.Rows.Count > 1)
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully read oracle.");
            }
        }
```

Again, I've used MyServiceId in the third-party tool's wizard and I connect just fine and select my database.  I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client. I consulted a number of articles online including [Oracle's guidance in section "Getting Started with ODP.NET, Managed Driver"](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/dotnet/Web_version_Fully_Managed_ODPnet_OBE/odpnetmngdrv.html).  How can I get the driver to recognize the valid service id and then also accept the database name? Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I wish I had a more definitive explanation but as it turns out the code from my original question works NOW using the connection string defined in variable "cxn".  I ran it many times before with no success, so my only guess is that the DBA changed something or rebooted the server since initial configuration.